# A better way to utilise local storage to store shopping cart details

Tags: javascript, local-storage, shopping-cart

I am currently developing an e-commerce website. The website will not have a login-page as we are not keeping the user details in the database. Instead, we will be keeping the user's email to contact them. Hence, we will not be having a user table in the database. In order to persist data in the user's shopping cart, we will be storing it using local storage. However, I was afraid that some malicious users will tamper with the contents in the cart, such as the product price. Hence, I **might** consider storing the productIDs in the local storage instead and then retrieve the specific products from my database as the user reloads the page.

Is this solution robust? Is there a better way to utilise local storage to store the user's shopping cart, or is there an alternative to local storage?

Comment: As you said you should store the product ID but anything like price should just be for display purposes, never trust it and always use the important details from the server

Comment: Hi @Dominic thanks for the reply! Also, I forgot to mention that I will be storing user uploaded images as well using local storage. Is that a good idea?

Comment: Yes it's fine to store anything locally (there are also other storage options) as long as you accept this data can be lost (clearing browser cache, opening on another device) and you aren't depending on the idea the user won't tamper with it (it's their problem if something breaks due to tampering but shouldn't compromise your system)

Comment: Also think about how a user could fake being someone else. If a user logs in using a traditional approach they get an encoded token, the backend decrypts that and checks it is valid and gets the user details from a database. Your way the user could just say "this is my email address, make the purchase on this account" - it's ok for one off purchases but don't trust them if you have a user account system and they haven't logged into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The quick and simple answer:

> *"Sanitize the user's cart data **BEFORE** sending it to the back-end and check it against a pre-defined product database to make sure the products exist and that they actually cost what's specified by the cart data."*

#### The long, detailed answer:

You should implement a three stage system to verify the user's cart data:

1. Check the user's email against your email list / database
2. Sanitize the user's cart data **BEFORE** sending it to the back-end
3. Verify the cart's products against pre-defined database of products

By doing so you prevent hackers from:

1. Using fake user data to purchase products
2. Modifying product data
3. Making products more/less expensive
4. Using the user's cart data to inject malicious code into your back-end
5. Creating/purchasing fake/non-existent products

You should also use the browser's built in features to [escape user input](http://shebang.brandonmintern.com/foolproof-html-escaping-in-javascript/):

```
function escape_input(data) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
  return div.innerHTML;
}
```

Because (according to the linked website):

> *"It's important to be constantly vigilant with the handling of user data. To avoid <s>SQL</s> injection, never build database queries by concatenating user-supplied data. These measures protect the integrity of the data on our servers."*

I'd also suggest having some sort of identification verification system that's required **BEFORE** the user can make a purchase.

A good example of this is Google's two step verification system, which requires you to input a code sent to you via text message/phone call into an input form.

This is done to verify the identity of the user and to prevent people from accessing/using other people's accounts, this system is almost impossible to fraud but it's also easy to implement it incorrectly, so I'd take that advice with a grain of salt.

Unfortunately, as you have not specified any code, I cannot determine how secure your site is.

If you create a new question with that code and link it here, I'd be more than happy to try and help you out with your application's security flaws (if there are any).

Good luck and stay safe.

Answer (score 1):

you are correct, you should only use ids, and extra properties of data. all important things, like price quantity... should be saved on server side and you have to query them by ids. local storage is good options but it has limit about 5mb, if you store much data it will overload and cannont save anymore. if you just have to save ids, that's fine otherwise I suggest to use indexDB for that, I recommend you check https://dexie.org/ this library, if you prefer to work with indexDB

Comment: Hi onkik, I appreciate your reply. I just read the documentation that you send me and I am still not clear what is indexDB. What is the difference between local storage and indexDB?

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that I will be storing user uploaded images as well using local storage. Is that a good idea?

Comment: index db is like database storage on client-side, it's like non-relational database and you can store there much more, than in local-storage

Comment: no if y want to store images you just add cache-control header to your request, so browser will cache images automatically

Comment: Hi onik, just to clarify one last thing. So I should consider using local storage or index db to store the productIDs, price and quantity and implement a new method called caching specifically for images only?

Comment: yes you shoud use index db or local storage for storing user data, and if y want to cache images, upload it to server and then use browser caching mechanism, you can read this article for it https://varvy.com/pagespeed/cache-control.html